# How to parse txt file and make changes to a excel file based on the txt file in python

Tags: python, excel

I have a txt file with he following format and everyday I would like to run a python script so that the Name column, and end date column is used to parse the status column and make changed to a spreadsheet accordingly.

Txt file format:

```
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| Name        | c2                  | start               | end                 | status
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| N1         | d1                  | 2023-02-08 02:01:45 | 2023-02-08 08:15:01 | completed
| N2         | d2                  | 2023-02-09 06:04:25 | 2023-02-09 10:35:50 | completed
| N1         | d2                  | 2023-02-09 06:04:25 | 2023-02-09 10:35:50 | completed
| N1         | d2                  | 2023-02-10 13:46:01 | 2023-02-10 16:35:50 | completed
| N4         | d2                  | 2023-02-10 16:35:25 | 2023-02-10 19:35:50 | started
| N1         | d2                  | 2023-02-11 16:35:25 | 2023-02-11 19:35:50 | completed
| N3         | d2                  | 2023-02-11 16:35:25 | 2023-02-11 19:35:50 | completed
| N2         | d2                  | 2023-02-11 16:35:25 | 2023-02-11 19:35:50 | started
| N4         | d2                  | 2023-02-12 18:54:03 | 2023-02-12 23:53:09 | started
```

Spreadsheet:
[image]

Since all the columns in the spreadsheet have been filled out until the 11th. If I run the python script for 12/02/2023, then with respect to the txt file above, the spreadsheet would have the N4 on 12/02/2023 changed from waiting to Started.

Is this possible based on the weirdly formatted txt file?

I was thinking using openyxl and thinking of edge cases I could add in the future like if it starts on the 11th then ends on the 12th, then the status on the spreadsheet should change for the end date.. but for now id just like something simple I can wrap my head around. Sorry if this doesn't make sense

Comment: Is the output file an xls/xlsx (not a csv)? Sounds like it is, if you're planning to use openpyxl.

Comment: From your problem description, it seems like you should be able to do what you want. If you can describe it, you can almost certainly write software to perform it. Have you written any code that you need help with?

Comment: sorry yes @jarmod the output file would be xls/xlsx thanks for correcting

Comment: hi @jarmod the above code converts it into a df well however lets say I get a new txt file that has dates for 12/02 and 13/02.. how would I be able to add the data for that new date from the txt file to a xlsx/xls file similar to the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='|', skiprows=(0, 2,)).iloc[:, 1:].applymap(str.strip)
```

- read_csv: reads the csv
- skiprows: ignores row 0 and 2 because they are (malformated)
- iloc[]: slices the dataframe and removes the first column (malformated)
- applymap: applies a function on each cell of the dataframe
- str.strip: the function removes leading or following whitespaces

Comment: Does pandas read_csv also read native Excel xls/xlsx formats?

Comment: @jarmod you can use pd.read_excel() for that instead, why are you asking?

Comment: OP mentions openpyxl.

Comment: @jarmod ah, I assumed this is not a requirement but an idea for a solution.